# Disable console log in react navigation

Tags: react-native

I'm using react navigation for my app development. When i run log-android, it keeps logging something like this.

Navigation Dispatch: Action: {...}, New State: {...}

which is from createNavigationContainer.js line 150.

I've run through github and document said it could be done by  by setting onNavigationStateChange={null} on a top-level navigator.

How can i achieve this by setting onNavigationStateChange={null} and where should i set it?

I've try to set like below, but it the page will not be able to redirect to other page.

```
export default () => {
 <App onNavigationStateChange={null} />
}
```

Below are my app.js code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator,DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import DrawerContent from './components/drawer/drawerContent.js';

import News from './components/news/home.js';

    const drawNavigation = DrawerNavigator(
      {
        Home : {
           screen : News ,
           navigationOptions : {
             header : null
           }
         }
      },
      {
        contentComponent: props => <DrawerContent {...props} />
      }
    )

    const StackNavigation = StackNavigator({
      Home : { screen : drawNavigation,
        navigationOptions: {
          header: null
        }
       }
    });


    export default StackNavigation;
```

This is my drawerContent.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {View,Text, StyleSheet,
  TouchableNativeFeedback,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native'
import { DrawerItems, DrawerView } from 'react-navigation';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Octicons';
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

class DrawerContent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
      console.log('DrawerContent|testtttttt');
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Hi darren</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginBottom:5 }} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('RegistrationScreen') } >
          <View style={styles.nonIconButton}>
            <Text  style={{ color: 'black',fontSize: 13 }} >Sign Up</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text>Hi darren</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});


export default DrawerContent;
```

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure you are using the latest release of `react-navigation` as [the comment noting that the fix was committed](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/360#issuecomment-296690849) is fairly recent.

Based on your code example, to disable logging for all navigation state changes, you would want to replace this code:

```
export default StackNavigation;
```

with:

```
export default () => (
  <StackNavigation onNavigationStateChange={null} />
);
```

as `StackNavigation` appears to be your root navigator.

Comment: I have no idea why the default `onNavigationStateChange` function logs so much even though it costs slower performance. Makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

React navigation is great, but this logging is really bad. Solution

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(SomeAppRouteConfigs);
    class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <AppNavigator onNavigationStateChange={null} /> 
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: This worked really well for me! The other examples weren't so clear, thanks!